# Ruby inherit specific methods

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I have this problem. I want to make a class which inherits from Array. Then I can just do this

```
class MyClass < Array
```

However, I only want to inherit a number of methods , not all of them, so my class won't be messed up by calling on the unintended methods from the parent

Comment: Then don't inherit. Wrap.

Comment: I am a bit lost on how to achieve that. can you elaborate on the wrap?

Comment: you should look at mix-ins /modules for that.  What features of array are you looking for?

Comment: array is just an example. I am just curious if there's a built in way to do this directly. Seems unlikely.

Comment: composition over inheritance! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic pattern to do this in ruby is by using mix-ins.  Since you want array features, Im not entirely sure, but I feel like you may be wanting the power of enumerable in your class.  If that is the case, then all you have to do is define a class, include enumerable, and then define the method `each`, from which all the other methods in enumerable are defined.

```
class MyClass
  include Enumerable

  def initialize *foos
    @foos = foos
  end

  def each(&block)
    @foos.each(&block)
  end
```

Comment: I figured that another way to do this is to override the method_missing and prohibit unwanted method call. Thanks for introducing mixins. I had no idea how to use it until now

Comment: eh, overriding method_missing is a bit more meta-programmish and not needed in this use case.  But mix-ins are very familiar to most rubyists, so I think this is definitely the way to go.  This capability, especially with Enumerable, makes ruby very fun to program with.

Comment: the method missing doesn't really work (I was hoping ruby would have something like a hook before methods are called). Now I should read more  into Mixin. Thanks for the info. : )